# OMG magento has 400 tables in MySQL DB?

Tags: database

Oh my dear i just looked at database and it has almost 400 tables. 
This is crazy they designed Magento to run off government grade servers?
Average hosting like godaddy shared is not a Disney land its taking like 5 seconds for each page to load or more yeah cache helps for front end, but not admin, why they went for this ridiculous database structure that they bragging about. This is not practical real world solution.

Another area is the filesystem, its almost 100MB uncompressed on clean install 12,467 Files, 4,696 Folders omg i have not seen e-commerce or CMS that has so many files, developing custom extensions is pain as well because their MVC architecture and other "good stuff" that is highly inefficient bloated and written like high school project.

Other than that i can live with admin interface, but i am procedural pattern guy and its against my belief system to use OOP and MVC so editing core files is only common sense approach i found.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Hey, I have to close this because it's either earnestly awesome but totally inappropriate for this format OR it's an excellent trolling of Magento. I am (and I'm sure others would be) 100% happy to hang out and discuss Magento with you in various forums and via several media. My Twitter is @benmarks, my email is ben.marks@magento.com, and ~six years ago I had a similar reaction (though tables were only around 200 and sample data was smaller).

Comment: Understood i just had to say it. I kinda like Magento at user/admin level, but not as a developer.

Answer (score 7):

> *"Oh my dear i just looked at database and it has almost 400 tables."*

The database for Magento is as big as it needs to be. You should [look into EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for a partial understanding regarding the number of tables (though Magento has - as usual - a unique take on the topic), and you should also realize that there are a number of indices and entities which can be resolved to these tables.

> *"Average hosting like godaddy shared is... taking like 5 seconds for each page to load"*

So, this is where Magento steps away from other OS commerce apps. eCommerce apps (especially ones which run the spectrum from mom & pop to MB enterprise) are worthy of some infrastructure, and as we've often said in the IRC channel, "You shouldn't run Magento on a toaster." Minimum specs can be found [here](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements), though you should always look for proper processor allocation and a secure filesystem; neither of these can be found at a shared host. To answer a question with a question: "How much is your eCommerce business worth, especially considering security? Find something besides shared hosting."

**Regarding the filesystem:** yes there are a lot of files. This is due mainly to the OOP MVC architecture and to both the depth and breadth of functionality + theming. The size of the app directory is large, but its contents are well-handled by a proper IDE like PhpStorm of Zend Studio.

> *"i am procedural pattern guy and its against my belief system to use OOP and MVC"*

Sorry, but "tough luck" on this one. OOP + MVC is the world you are dealing with if you want to use Magento.

There is a big community and there are a lot of resources for you - please let us know how we can help!

Comment: thx Magento love boy, my bad its 250 tables actually i miscalculated at first.

Comment: Enterprise Edition will get you to 400 tables :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, given you sound technically competent, but

> OMG magento has 400 tables in MySQL DB?

No, Magento does not have 400 tables -- it's closer to 350, although each installation will have a different number of tables depending on the number of modules installed and the version of Magento you're using. (modules may add a number of additional tables). If you need help counting the tables in the future, the following SQL query

```
SHOW TABLES:
```

Will list all the tables, and most MySQL clients will let you know how many rows it found (which will correspond to the number of tables)